# Can I fetch multiple icon images through the same HTTP connection in Android?

Tags: android, image, http

My app contains a list, where each item has the image icon inside. All icons are available on the server over HTTP.

My code to load the images is currently simple:

```
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
                imageUrl.openConnection();
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
```

and then read image from the stream, and then there is the end of the stream, and then ... that .. close the connection. However this provides one image only. To get another one even from the same folder on the server, I need to open another connection.

I am aware there is connection setup time, hence with lots of tiny icons loading would be faster if to take all images in one request. Since HTTP 1.1 should be possible to reuse the connection for another image. How to do this?

I also looked into Android image loaders like Picaso, they have very nice API but seem accepting only single image at time:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(myImageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Or, with UniversalImageLoader:

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Unless they do some highly transparent magic, the loaders seem making image loading easier to program but I need to make it faster instead.

Comment: the `is` carry one image so? why you didn't get images urls and display them with picasso simply..

Comment: Will Picasso reuse the connection? I want this to be fast first, simple is optional.

Comment: glide more faster in your case, and also i think it will be faster if the image came with url instead of `inputStream` data, you gave the picasso or image loader double work to do now, 
reading `is` and fetching images.

Comment: iterate your code block and the underlying conn gets reused... details ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html